# Bootstrap Datepicker Example

Tags: django-crispy-forms

I cannot seem to get the bootstrap datepicker from http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/ to work using the example from https://gist.github.com/maraujop/2812529.

The only thing I am unsure of is where to put the datepicker folder after downloading it? I put it in my static folder and while I get no errors the only thing that shows up on my form for a date field is a blank looking box next to the field but nothing comes up when pressing it.

This doesn't seem like it should be that hard but for whatever reason, this isn't working.

Any suggestions(something that works).

Thanks

Comment: look at the renderd mark up, or paste it in jsfiddle for people to take a look

Comment: The output looks like: <div  
    class="span3" ><div id="div_id_date_of_birth" class="control-group "><label for="id_date_of_birth" class="control-label requiredField">
            Date of Birth<span class="asteriskField">*</span></label><div class="controls"><div class="input-append"><input class="dateinput" id="id_date_of_birth" name="date_of_birth" type="text" /> <span class="add-on "></span></div></div></div></div>

Comment: you need to include the js scripts from the folder and then onpage load init the control $('#dpd1').datepicker('#id_date_of_birth')...

Comment: I do load the scripts but did not do that on the page. I will try that since the example did not state that. Thanks.

Comment: I tried that and all that does is place the exact text above the control itself. Can't be I am doing this correctly?

Comment: its very hard to advise without seeing a running version of the code, could you put that in jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [django-bootstrap3-datetimepicker](https://github.com/nkunihiko/django-bootstrap3-datetimepicker) which you can install with pip and add to `INSTALLED_APPS`. Works very well for me.

There's an [alternative](https://github.com/zokis/django-bootstrap-datetimepicker) listed in the docs for Bootstrap2, but I've not used it so can't comment on how well it works.